# Como manter menu aberto após :active

Tags: html, css

Tenho um menu feito exclusivamente com css e html. Ao clicar no botão ele abre o menu, mas se eu solto o botão ele desaparece, para manter o menu aberto eu preciso ficar segurando o botão do mouse. Queria opiniões de como posso corrigir isso, apenas clicar uma vez e abrir o menu e continuar aberto e se eu movimentar o ponteiro do mouse para a navbar ele desaparece normalmente.

Detalhes no site codepen: https://codepen.io/flashpremium/pen/zzYKBR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta trocar o :active por :hover. Testei no codepen na linha 63 do teu css

```
.top-menu > li:hover .megadrop {
```

Não sei se é esse o resultado que você esperava.

Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, mas já havia tentado desta forma, só que pretendo abrir o menu somente após o clique no botão.

Comment: Você quer então um menu desse jeito? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar_click

Comment: Sim, exatamente desse jeito.

Comment: Você pode usar javascript? No exemplo que te passei precisa de javascript para ativar o menu. Ainda precisa de ajuda pra adaptar teu código ao exemplo?

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, vou utilizar o exemplo acima para adaptar no menu.